# Formatting main chart's axis in C#

Tags: c#, .net, forms, charts

I'm trying to make chart in C# which should be readable easily. I managed to draw sin() graph, but it's not really readable, as X and Y axis don't stand out, I feel like it's the middle of nowhere. I tried to set line width using following code:

```
area.AxisX.LineWidth = 3;
```

But it only made line in the bottom of chart fatter, not main axis (Y = 0) like I need.
Anyone know how I would accomplish that? Is Y axis (X = 0) same? If no, could you please specify how to bold it too?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is the MajorGridLines:

```
area.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 3
```

Or maybe this:

```
area.AxisX.LineWidth = 3;
area.AxisX.Crossing = 0;
area.AxisY.LineWidth = 3;
area.AxisY.Crossing = 0;
```

Crossing will put the axis at the value you set it to.

Comment: Sadly no. It simply bolded all horizontal lines. Though thanks for attempt, I haven't tried this one.

Comment: I made an edit to my original answer. The Crossing property might help you out.